# Including commands from separate Ruby file

Tags: ruby, siri

I have a chunk of code that has commands. I want to keep more commands in a separate file and pull them into the main. Thus my main file can be updated without losing any custom commands. How would I go about that?

```
{
class myClass()

#commands
listen_for /what is your name/i do

  say "my name is mud"

end

## Insert Custom.rb here ##
# Everything in the custom rb file is just ike the "listen_for" command above

end
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The answe above will not work in this case because there is no listen_for methods defined in the custom.rb file**

wrap whatever you have in `custom.rb` in a module, like

```
module Foo
  # commands
end
```

require your file `custom.rb` on the top of your script and include it in your class:

```
require_relative './custom.rb'

class myClass()
  include Foo
  # code here
end
```

**This is the new try**

Remove the `module` wrapper in the listen_for commands, and instead simply list them in the `custom.rb` as you would do inside your main class definition. And in your main class, Read and eval it, like this:

```
class myClass()
  eval(File.read('./custom.rb'))
  # code here
end
```

Comment: partially working. as I am include more listen_for commands in the custom.rb file I get the error undefined method "listen_for"

Comment: what do you mean by "include more listen_for" commands? Can you edit your question and include how your files looks like and what is the error?

Comment: my class is exactly like the above. I am working with siri proxy. listen_for is a command it accepts. This is the main siriproxy.rb file. What I want to do is kkep the user from editing this file. So I want the user to put all of thier "listen_for" commands in a seperate file and include it. I have gotten it included with fontanus suggestion. But now I run into undefined method "listen_for" when gets pulled in.

Comment: I see. Edited my answer, take a look.

Comment: still getting the undefind method "listen_for" for main:Object

Comment: ruby is still a little new to me but can't i just include the contests of a file in my main code page as I would in other languages?

Comment: @SeeleyBoothe perhaps you should keep alert for answers on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450640/how-to-execute-local-functions-using-code-from-external-file-in-ruby) I just made. I'm also confused with this output.

Comment: i will do that. This is driving me crazy!

Comment: got the answer from your question fontanus. The eval thing worked for. Just got to get it to use a variable for the path name now. But this is great.

Comment: @SeeleyBoothe good, corrected my answer for completeness. :-)

Comment: hey fontanus new prob. I need to use a variable in the path: eval(File.read('#{@config_Path}/custom-commands.rb')). I have tried with double quotes and every other thing I can think of. says it cant find the file. That variable does work and is set. Need to use the path cuz ./custom-commands.rb doesnt find it either. This is a app on ubuntu not a web project.