# How to execute local functions using code from external file in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Can a require execute a locally defined function? I guess the easiest way to describe what I need is to show an example.

I'm using ruby 1.9.3, but solutions for 1.8 and 2.0 are also welcome.

I have a file main.rb as the following:

```
class Stuff
  def self.do_stuff(x)
    puts x
  end
  require_relative('./custom.rb')

  do_stuff("y")
end
```

And also have a file custom.rb in the same folder, with the following content:

```
do_stuff("x")
```

Running main.rb, I have following output:

```
/home/fotanus/custom.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `do_stuff' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
    from main.rb:5:in `require_relative'
    from main.rb:5:in `<class:Stuff>'
    from main.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Note that without the `require`, the output is `y`.

Comment: Why do you need `do_stuff("x")` to be bare? Can't you put that within a method and call the method from main.rb?

Comment: @sawa Can't because of [siri](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449815/including-commands-from-separate-ruby-file/16449899?noredirect=1#comment23598165_16449899)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is the best solution but using `eval` should do the trick.

```
class Stuff
  def self.do_stuff(x)
    puts x
  end
  eval(File.read('./custom.rb'))

  do_stuff("y")
end
```

The output will be:

```
pigueiras@pigueiras$ ruby stuff.rb 
x
y
```

Comment: Thanks, lets see if someone come up with something better, but this works.

Answer (score 2):

In C, `#include` literally drops the code as-is into the file. `require` in Ruby is different: it actually runs the code in the required file in its own scope. This is good, since otherwise we could break `require`d code by redefining things before the `require`.

If you want to read in the contents of a script and evaluate it in the current context, there are methods for doing just that: `File.read` and `eval`.